# MIchaelis-Menten with additional covariate

Tags: nonlinear-regression, predictor

I have some data that can be fit with a saturating curve and I have been using a Michaelis-Menten function fit with nls() in R:

```
#get starting value estimates
Vm <- getInitial(y ~ SSmicmen(x, max(y), 1), data = dat)[1]
K <- getInitial(y ~ SSmicmen(x, max(y), 1), data = dat)[2]
#fit Michaelis-Menten model
m.m <- nls(y ~ SSmicmen(x, Vm, K), data = dat)
```

However, I have a second continuous variable and I want to test its effect on the parameters of the saturating curve. I have been unable to find any example like this, but I suspect it should be fairly simple.

Edit: For some background about the data I am trying to model - In the basic model (above) the response (y) is the number of species that occur in a location (local richness) and the predictor (x) is the number species that could possibly occur there (regional species richness), and I have data for many regions. I used a saturating function to describe this relationship because there is likely to be some maximum number of species that can co-occur in any given location. The secondary predictor that I am interested in incorporating is some property of the regional pool of species. For example, the functional diversity. It would be reasonable to predict that a more functionally diverse regional pool of species would allow for more species to coexist locally and a higher asymptote than a regional species pool where the species were all more similar.

Comment: There's more than one way one might put an additional covariate into such a model. Can you explain more clearly how you think this relates to the present model? i.e. what's E(Y) = ... in terms of the two variables you have?

Comment: I am actually not sure how I expect the additional variable to relate to the model parameters. I will edit the post to add some additional detail about the data that may clarify the problem enough for some to offer a suggestion.

Comment: Some things to think about: Let's call the new variable *z*. 1. If you held x constant, what would the relationship of z with y look like? 2. Would changing z tend to affect saturation level (Vm), or leave saturation unchanged? 3. Would increasing z change the rate of the reaction as a function of x (e.g. affect K)? 4. Would it change the *shape* of the relationship in some other way?

Comment: Glen_b - I primarily expect the additional predictor to affect Vm (see edit above), however, I would think that the 1/2 saturation would also likely change and that the general shape of the curve would remain similar across values of the covariate.

Comment: Thanks, that's at least something to go on, though it would be better for theory to suggest the modifcation than our guesses (most of us not knowing that particular area in much detail). Aside from direct theory, are there any other studies or other data  that might help to narrow it down ?

Comment: It might be of some help to consider a [Lineweaver-Burk plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lineweaver%E2%80%93Burk_plot), or even (by looking at a regression on the reciprocal-reciprocal scale used by that plot) to look at added variable plots for the new variable; that might give some idea of how it comes in.

Comment: Thanks. I will take a look at those approaches. What I have done at this point after fitting the MM model is extract the residuals and plot them against the original predictor, with points colored by the new predictor. There was a clear pattern, so I set up a second model and found that there is a significant effect of the interaction between the two predictors on the residuals.

Comment: Examine residuals against the new variable to identify lack of fit. Note however, that by using the data to choose a model, if you use the same data to calculate p-values, standard errors and so on, this will impact their properties (everything will look better than it really is, for one thing). I meant to raise this issue before.